# nextLine().split("\\s+") converted to python

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me what

```
nextLine().split("\\s+")
```

does and how would I convert that to python?

Thanks

i wanted to use it but its in java

Comment: What language is this from?

Comment: The first step would be to read the java documentation. I don't program java normally and don't have the docs at hand, but a quick internet search got https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/, so I assume this is a regular expression split on whitespace and python's `re.split` would be the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

`split` takes an input string, possibly a regular expression (in your case) and uses the regex as a delimiter. Here, the regex is simply `\s+` (the extra backslash is to escape the string), where `\s` denotes any sort of white space and `+` means "one or more", so basically, if I have the string `"Hello  world !      ."` you will have the output `["Hello", "world", "!", "."]`.

In Python, you need to use the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library for this functionality:

```py
re.split(r"\s+", input_str)
```

Or, just for this specific case (as @Kurt pointed out), `input_str.split()` will do the trick.

Comment: are you sure?  input_str.split() works just fine if we really just care about whitespace

Comment: @Kurt you're right. I don't really use Python so I wasn't aware, but now I know.

Answer (score 2):

The `nextLine()` is used to read user input, and `split("\\s+")` will split it to a bunch of elements based on a specific delimiter, and for this case the delim is a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `\\s+`.

The equivalent of it in python is this, by using the  :

```
import re

s = input()
sub_s = re.split(r"\s+", s)

# hello and welcome everyone 
# ['hello', 'and', 'welcome', 'everyone']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Hello my Wonderful\nWorld!";

o = s.split("\n")
print ("'" + o[0] + "'")
print ("'" + o[1] + "'")
'''

resp. use of
i = s.find('\n')
print (s[:i])
print (s[i+1:])

e.g.
def get_lines(str):
    start = 0
    end = 0
    sub = '\n'
    while True:
        end = str.find(sub, start)
        if end==-1:
            yield str[start:]
            return
        else:
            yield str[start:end]
        start = end + 1

i = iter(get_lines(s))
print ("'" + next (i) + "'")
print ("'" + next (i) + "'")

'''

o = s.split()
print ("*" + o[2] + "*")
```

output

```
'Hello my Wonderful'
'World!'
*Wonderful*
```